# not able to fetch the record from mongodb by passing the value field and collection name as parameters in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i am tring to fetch whether the record is present or not so  i am passing the value , field of the mongo db and collection name as parameters and i am unable   to fetch the record from the database . but if i remove the field name and given directly in search function it is working . i dont know why it is not working if i give input for field also .

```
dboperations.search(req.body.userid,"userid" ,"customers",function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
```

i am calling the search function using this and the search function definition was

```
exports.search=function(value,field,collection,callback){

   mongo.get().collection(collection).find({field:value}).toArray(function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result)
        callback(result)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic object key

```
exports.search=function(value,field,collection,callback){

   mongo.get().collection(collection)
        .find({[field]:value}) // <- fix is here
        .toArray(function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result)
        callback(result)
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks man its working , can i know  whats the concept behind this so that i can go through it

Comment: @vamsireddy Here is one short article http://wtfruby.com/javascript/2017/01/04/js-dynamic-attr-names.html

Comment: @vamsireddy Pretty much the issue you had was that {field:value} means that you are searching for a field named 'field' with a value of value.

Comment: @vamsireddy but {[field]: value} means that you would be searching for a field with a value of field variable not the string 'field'

Answer (score 1):

Enlace your variables with [], so they will be interpreted for the request like this :

```
mongo.get().collection(collection).find({[field]:[value]}).toArray(err, result) {

});
```

Comment: sorry i cant understand it

Comment: Cool ! Don't forget to validate the response

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.search=function(value,field,collection,callback){

mongo.get().collection(collection).find({field:value}).toArray(function(err, 
result) {

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result)
    callback(result)
});
}
```

> try this code